# Sum specific column value until a certain value is reached

Tags: awk, text-processing

I want to print first column's value until its reached a certain value, like;

```
43  12.00   53888
29  10.00   36507
14  9.00    18365
8   8.00    10244
1   7.00    2079
1   9.50    1633
0   6.00    760
```

I would like the output to be:

val = 90

```
43  12.00   53888
29  10.00   36507
14  9.00    18365
```

Comment: 43+29+14 is 86 though

Comment: Updated value to 90.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain which numbers you're summing to get the result `90` and to show what you've tried yourself so far.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Here is a short awk that does it for you: `awk -v v=90 '((s+=$1) > v){exit}1' file `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples. Explicitly putting `exit` in condition when 1st column's sum goes greater than mentioned value to avoid unnecessary reading rest of the Input_file.

```
awk -v val="90" '($1+prev)>val{exit} ($1+prev)<=val{print}{prev+=$1}' Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk -v val="90" '($1+prev)>val{exit} ($1+prev)<=val; {prev+=$1}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v val="90" '     ##Starting awk program from here and mentioning variable val as 90 here.
($1+prev)>val{        ##Checking condition if first field and prev variable sum is greater than val then do following.
  exit                ##exit from program to save some time.
}
($1+prev)<=val;       ##Checking condition if sum of $1 and prev is lesser than or equal to val then print the current line.
{
  prev+=$1            ##keep adding 1st field to prev variable here.
}
' Input_file          ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 3):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -sape ' $s += $F[0] ; exit if $s > $vv' -- -vv=90 file
```

- `-s` enables setting variables from the command line, `-vv=90` sets the `$vv` variable to 90
- `-p` processes the input line by line, it prints each line after processing
- `-a` splits each line on whitespace and populates the @F array

The variable $s is used to hold the running sum. The line is printed only when the sum is less than $vv, once the sum is too large, the program exits.

Answer (score 2):

Consider small one-line awk

Revised: (Sep 2020): Modified to take into account Bruno's comments, going for readable solution, see kvantour for compact solution.

```
awk -v val=85 '{ s+= $1 ; if ( s > val ) exit ; print }'
```

Original Post: (Aug 2020)

```
awk -v val=85 '{ s += $1 ; if ( s <= val ) print }'
```

Or even

```
awk -v val=85 '{ s+= $1 } s <= val'
```

Comment: if a value is negative making `s <= val` true again you do not follow OP requirement

Comment: @dash-o nice answer `awk -v val=85 '{ s+= $1 } s <= val'`

Answer (score 1):

Consider an even smaller awk which is very much in line with the [solution of dash-o](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63055740/8344060)

```
awk -v v=90 '((v-=$1)<0){exit}1' file
```

or the smallest:

```
awk -v v=90 '0<=(v-=$1)' file
```